# Grails 3 push notifications

Tags: ajax, grails, push-notification

I have got a grails app and a java app which  sometimes sends messages to grails and calls some functions. It works fine, but  my current task is to get error message from java and show it in my view without refreshing page.
I've read that push events plugins could help me in this task, but I haven't find any plugin  working with grails 3.3.0.

So, how can I solve this task?
How bad is solution to send get ajax requests from client to server, and if server has any flag then send message in response?

Comment: you could look into JMS (Java Message Service) there is a plugin for grails and is pretty solid and simple setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For server to web client push you can use [Server Send Events](http://guides.grails.org/server-sent-events/guide/index.html) which is built into Grails or [Spring Websockets](https://github.com/zyro23/grails-spring-websocket) which has a lot more functionality such as 2 way communication, topics, etc. Both work with Grails 3.3.x

As you mentioned a polling ajax request may be simple enough to meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Am I understand correctly,that SSE is not a long pooling ajax but a different entity? Correct me, if I am wrong. Client initialises connection to server and when server has any messages, it sends it back? 
I mean there is only one request client -> server and there may be lots of messages server -> client? If it's so, it fits me prefectly.